# float:left shifting next rows div block to left position when expanded

Tags: javascript, html, css

Look at my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/techprasad/fJUaD/).
You need to resize Result panel so that you can view at least two block inline. If you click on "`More details`" link then it will show details but it will shift next rows block also.

Any suggestion why this it is showing like this though I have used `clear:both`.

```
.reviewimg_blk {
    border: 1px solid #9B9B9B;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 395px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a common problem with floats.

Use `display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;` instead of `float:left;` if you don't need IE7 support.

See https://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/ for a cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of `position:relative`. `Position:relative` keeps div's or blocks in a relation so the below block was moving down. Use instead `position:absolute` at the places related to that dropdown part.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I used relative because I want them to take position right after current block ends. if I make it absolute then all block will show at same position (or I need to specify top and left position). also this code is repeated in loop.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your 1st `itemStyle` div has more content so it is taking more height than other divs.

So add `<div class="clear"> </div>` after every two `itemStyle` divs or fix the min-height to the `itemStyle` div.

I have added `clear` class after every two `itemStyle` divs in demo.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fJUaD/1/)**

Comment: Thanks but don't you think that adding clear after two block will restrict page to show only two blocks at one row? and also I don't want to specify any hard coded height.

Answer (score 0):

..***[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fJUaD/4/)***

Hi now used to `Even` and `odd` rules in css

```
.itemStyle:nth-child(odd) {
clear:left;
    float:left;
}
```

more info [**even or odd**](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html) rules

Comment: Thanks rohit. That works but its putting restriction on page to show only two block in single row ( if width is less means on lower resolution) on wide resolution also it showing only two blocks in row.